# High-performance Math library for .NET /C# and Java

Tags: c#, java, c++, tbb, intel-mkl

We currently have a high-performance scientific application written in C++ that makes use of [Intel Math Kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/).

We are considering writing a benchmark application written in Java and .NET/C# to compare the performance difference. To do that, we also need a good (commercial is preferred) math library for both. Does anyone know of any math equivalent library for Java/C#?

As a sidenote: C++ has [Intel TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) library to help with multithreading. Does .NET/C# and Java have something equivalent?

Comment: have you thought about just writing a wrapper for the C++ library for C# and Java?

Comment: Java has java.util.concurrent and subpackages. I'm not too familiar with TBB, but this is Sun's way of doing threading.

Comment: @Aaron: yeah..i've thought about that too. thanks about the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol..why didnt I think of this before?

Just use Intel MKL Math library in Java and .NET!

See the following links:

- [Using MKL in Java app](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lin/MKL_UG_coding_calls/Invoking_Intel_MKL_Functions_from_Java_Applications.htm)
- [How to use MKL with Java](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-how-do-i-use-intel-mkl-with-java/)
- [Using MKL in C#](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-your-c-program/)
- [MKL 10.2 update](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/68490/)
- [MKL in depth](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/mkl/mkl_indepth.pdf)

Comment: The main argument is that the resulting C# code is no longer portable to e.g. mono/linux because it is reliant on an API/DLL running outside of the CLR.

Comment: thanks for the good thoughts. I posted a question on the Intel MKL forum to see if the MKL linux version will work with the Mono implementation or not. If not, what is their plan. Thanks again.

Comment: @the-locster: Intel responded that Mono is not supported *yet*. So man..too bad.

Answer (score 4):

I can help with C#:

Here is another SO question that discusses [various C# math libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net)

And you can take a look at [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28VS.100%29.aspx) for C# multithreading help.

Comment: hey..thanks for that link. Btw..are you in a scientific community? If so, do you use C# at work? do you have any experience with any C# (high-performance) math lib?

Comment: I write a discrete event simulation application called Micro Saint Sharp.  We switched from C to C# 7 years ago.  The performance is great.  I don't use any external math libraries.  The only special math class we use is for calculating various random distributions, performance of it has never been a simulation bottleneck.

Comment: I'm quite surprised performance of C# is on par with C. That's great to hear!

Comment: Our previous engine was written in C, but the simulation scripting engine was interpreted.  Now the simulation is compiled C#, so the performance is about 1000x over the old system.  I suspect carefully tuned C would beat C# for a lot of very heavy math operations.

Comment: Yeah, I found that the differential between C# and hand-tuned SIMDified microoptimzed C for linear algebra was about 10x. But that's a special case.

Answer (score 4):

For java:

http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems like that project has not been updated in a long time (since 2004?)

Answer (score 2):

[Math.NET Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/) supports Mono

Answer (score 1):

[ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/) is a cross-platform numerical analysis and data processing library. And it is free - ALGLIB is distributed under a GPL license (version 2 or later). It contains:

Differential equations

Linear equations

Matrix and vector operations, Eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Numerical integration, Interpolation and fitting, Optimization

FFT, convolution, correlation

Statistics: general algorithms, Hypothesis testing

Data analysis: classification, regression, other tasks

Special functions

Answer (score 0):

[SuanShu](http://numericalmethod.com/blog/suanshu/) is a large collection of numerical algorithms. It is well supported. It has both a Java and a FREE C# versions.